Make JButton paintComponent draw on top of parent's border
I have a verticalBox with a border of 1px on all sides. Insede the vb there are buttons. I would like for the selected button to draw on top of the right border of the vb. The desired result would be a continous line except for where the selected button is.
I unsuccessfully tried overriding the paintComponent of the button as follows:
@Override
 protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    shape = new Rectangle(0,0, this.getWidth() + 1, this.getHeight());
    g2.fill(shape);
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g2.dispose();
}

this is my verticalBox instantiaton:
Box typeVerticalBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
typeVerticalBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new Color(220,220,220)));


A component cannot draw outside of its own bounds.  But you can listen for changes to the button’s state, and update the Box’s border in the listener as you see fit.  Call addChangeListener or addItemListener on each button.
